# Indent specific cells in excel, bold text, highlight row and move files extension to next row

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to do the following with VBA and excel -

I have a large number if files names with extensions in column A. There are also folder names that do not contain extensions.

My goal is to have -

1. The extensions move to the next column
2. Indent (add two or three spaces) to the rows in column A that had an extension
3. Format the rows that only had folder names (no extensions) to a specific fill color and bold the text

I have tried the following already without VBA -

1. I open the list in excel from a txt file which allows me separate the extensions into the next column.
2. Used conditional formatting to then highlight and bold the rows that do not contain anything in column B now.

I have not found a way to indent though without VBA

[image: Example of info in column A]

Comment: Yes, this is possible - but note that SO is not meant to be a code-writing service. Have you tried any of this yourself, even with just taking a stab via the macro recorder?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have tried with some success. Importing a text file and sperating the extensions out that way. Then using some conditional formatting but it definitely does not come out very clean.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with what you have tried, instead of in a comment? Thanks!

Comment: It is def not my intent to use this as a code writing service. Even a quick example of any of the elements would go a long ways for me. Again thank you for your response.